# angular js multi select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in Validations|orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:org"  >
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.id" ng-checked="toggle">
    </td>
    <td"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session2" --disable-web-security>{{ x.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.lastUpdated }}</td>
    <td><dropdown-multiselect model="selectedUserIds" options="setting.instances"></dropdown-multiselect> 
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in selectedUserIds">{{ item }}Instance</li>
    </td>
</tr>
```

when i dynmiclly print the tble and print it when select the dropdown list it also shows that values in other rows s well.Why is that?

Comment: because you are binding it to the same model property?

Comment: so how do i tackle that thing?